# Turn on template path hits per user basis

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, template-hints

Is there a way of turning the path hits per user basis? When few people are working on the same website and one switches the template path hits on it messes the websites for all the users.

Any ideas how to overcome this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Just to clarify, we are all working from the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

Good question ... and no idea how to do it with default template hints.

I'd recommend to test this free extensions:

https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints

Template hints are displayed with adding `?ath=1` to your current url. Additionally it gives some more information then default function.